PC does not boot after installing nvidia driver on ubuntu 20.04 installed on encrypted disk
I just installed ubuntu 20.04 on a HP Z1 TO COMPLETE
I enabled LUKS disk encryption in the ubuntu installer, and ubuntu works well, no problem to boot.
After installing nvidia driver 470 then the PC cannot boot, this message is displayed:
[  0.725353] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
The PC boots if I select receovery mode in GRUB and then resume. Thanks to this, I can edit /etc/default/grub.
Setting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text nosplash" instead of "quiet splash" does not solve the issue.
nvidia driver is installed using: additional drivers utility => Select Using nvidia-driver-470
No problem if the disk is not encrypted.

Oh little mistake in the title, thanks for this feedback

The problem was caused by the nvidia driver which was not loaded correctly at boot, then I did not see the prompter to enter the password required to decrypt the disk.
Adding the nomodeset grub option fixes the issue:

Edit /etc/default/grub

Add nomodeset option into GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset ..."

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot


